# Mean diamond plot on boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, mean

I have a boxplot with a dot representing the mean:

[image: Boxplot with mean]

This is alright, but I'd like to show the confidence interval around the mean, for example in the following way:

[image: Diamond plot]

How can I overlay these two plots in R?

Comment: In the lower figure do you mean the limits of the CI to be situated vertically like the boxplot above or do you have another variable you're estimating on the x-axis?

Comment: I updated the question. I'd like to overlay the two plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function like the following is easy to write.
Enter the x and y for the mean, the upper limit, lower limit, and width of the diamond.  You can pass other parameters like lty for line type and col colour to segments as well.

```
diamondCI <- function(x, y, ul, ll, w = ul-ll, ...){
    hw <- w/2
    segments(x-hw, y, x+hw, y, ...)  # horizontal bar
    segments(x-hw, y, x, ul, ...) # left upper diag
    segments(x, ul, x+hw, y, ...) # right upper diag
    segments(x-hw, y, x, ll, ...) # left lower diag
    segments(x, ll, x+hw, y, ...) # right lwoer diag
    }
```

Try it out with...

```
plot(1,1)
diamondCI(1, 1, 1.2, 0.7, col = 'red', lwd = 3)
```